# R STM Topic Proportion table

Tags: r, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I'm trying to make a table for my STM model just like this.

[image]

I am new to R programming language and STM.

I have been searching in the documentation about this and do not know
if there is a function that makes just like this format
or if I have to manually make it like this.

Can I get some example on how to make a table like this and where can I get
Topic Proportions in % and if the topic has Appeared in Literate or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for expected topic proportion tables, the STM packages gives you a few options. For example, once you've generated your stm topic model object, you can pass the model through `plot.STM(mod, type = "summary", main = "title")` where `mod` is your stored model object, `summary` is the default table that this function generates, showing the expected proportion of the text corpus that belongs to a given topic (STM package, Roberts et al., 2018), and `main = "title"` is simply an optional command you can use to  label your figure. Alternatively, you can also pass your stored topic model through `plot(mod, type = "summary")` for a similar result.

As for extracting the exact % expected proportion by topic, I've had a similar question myself. Below is a custom workaround that I've recently implemented using the `make.dt` function from STM which outputs topic proportions by document.

`# custom proportion extraction  proportions_table <- make.dt(mod)  summarize_all(proportions_table, mean)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make it manually. Topic labels are manually defined. You can find theta which is the topic proportions matrix from the STM output.